# Expo React Native and Nodejs app - why cant I fetch data from my backend when running app using expo client app but can using ios simulator?

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

I have a react native app and a nodejs app. both working together. When Im running app on the ios simulator everything works fine (I can fetch data from my backend). When Im running it using expo client app, I cannot fetch any data or post any data from my nodejs backend. I always get:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
[AxiosError: Network Error]
```

I run my node server locally in development. Do I need to do anything differently?

Comment: does your backend URL depend on localhost?

Comment: yes it does, it only runs locally on localhost

Comment: replace localhost with your IP and make sure both the computer and the phone you test on are connected to the same network

Comment: I tried that but that doesnt work - I am getting same error (also in simulator when using ip address)